# Inner linear layouts buttons padding doesnt work

Tags: android, android-activity, android-xml

I have the button style code below, but I couldn't do padding between buttons.
The option is to make padding, I tryed. It didn't work.
Below my activity xml code, I'm using for the implementation

Thanks for any help

The selector code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:bottom="7dp" android:left="7dp" android:right="7dp" android:top="7dp" />

            <corners android:radius="0dip" />

            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#2c2f34" />

            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="#363c45" android:startColor="#090b0e" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:bottom="7dp" android:left="7dp" android:right="7dp" android:top="7dp" />

            <corners android:radius="0dip" />

            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#2c2f34" />

            <solid android:color="#1d242c" />
        </shape></item>
    <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:bottom="7dp" android:left="7dp" android:right="7dp" android:top="7dp" />

            <corners android:radius="0dip" />

            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#2c2f34" />

            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="#1d242c" android:startColor="#545c67" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>




styles.xml code



    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

        <style name="login_button_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
            <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
            <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
            <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
            <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
            <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
            <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
            <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.6</item>
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/login_buttons_style</item>
            <item name="android:padding">1dp</item>
        </style>

    </resources>

My activity xml code, here is the table 3X4, without padding between buttons

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_form_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- left outer layout -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- middle layout -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- middle top inner pincode-layout -->


            <!-- middle center inner layout keypad buttons, top row -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_form_button1"
                    style="@style/login_button_style"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/key_1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_form_button2"
                    style="@style/login_button_style"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/key_2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_form_button3"
                    style="@style/login_button_style"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/key_3" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- middle center inner layout keypad buttons, below-top row -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_form_button4"
                    style="@style/login_button_style"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/key_4" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_form_button5"
                    style="@style/login_button_style"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/key_5" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_form_button6"
                    style="@style/login_button_style"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/key_6" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- middle center inner layout buttons, above bottom row -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_form_button7"
                    style="@style/login_button_style"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/key_7" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_form_button8"
                    style="@style/login_button_style"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/key_8" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_form_button9"
                    style="@style/login_button_style"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/key_9" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- middle center inner layout buttons, bottom row -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_form_delete"
                    style="@style/login_button_style"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/delete" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_form_button0"
                    style="@style/login_button_style"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/key_0" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_form_login"
                    style="@style/login_button_style"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/login" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- middle inner bottom layout -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- right outer layout -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Give top and bottom margin to buttons in xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Use top and bottom margin to gap between buttons :

android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

Comment: Chhelena  thank you for answer, and how I can add it to style, and use it for all application's buttons, that using this style?

Comment: No just add margin in layout xml instead style.

Comment: thanks, it works for margin between internal horizontal layouts, and is it possible to implement margins between  buttons inside the horizontal layout in one place?